# Possible to reverse order of ItemGroup elements?

Tags: msbuild

In MSBuild 3.5, is it possible to reverse the order elements in an ItemGroup?

**Example**

I have 2 projects. One can be built independently the other is dependent on the first. Each project references its specific items in a .targets file.

**project_A.targets**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssembliesToRemove Include="@(AssembliesToRemove)" />
        <AssembliesToRemove Include="Assembly_A.dll">
            <ApplicationName>App_A</ApplicationName>
        </AssembliesToRemove>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AssembliesToDeploy Include="@(AssembliesToDeploy)" />
        <AssembliesToDeploy Include="Assembly_A.dll">
            <AssemblyType>SomeType</AssemblyType>
            <ApplicationName>App_A</ApplicationName>
        </AssembliesToDeploy>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**project_B.targets**

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssembliesToRemove Include="@(AssembliesToRemove)" />
        <AssembliesToRemove Include="Assembly_B.dll">
            <ApplicationName>App_B</ApplicationName>
        </AssembliesToRemove>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AssembliesToDeploy Include="@(AssembliesToDeploy)" />
        <AssembliesToDeploy Include="Assembly_B.dll">
            <AssemblyType>SomeType</AssemblyType>
            <ApplicationName>App_B</ApplicationName>
        </AssembliesToDeploy>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**project_A.proj**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Start" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="project_A.targets" />

    <Import Project="Common.targets" />
</Project>
```

**project_B.proj**

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Start" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="project_A.targets" />

    <Import Project="project_B.targets" />

    <Import Project="Common.targets" />
</Project>
```

**The Problem**

In this scenario the problem arises during the Task processing `@(AssembliesToDeploy)` because Assembly_B.dll needs to be deployed before Assembly_A.dll.

Processing `@(AssembliesToRemove)` works fine because here the assemblies are in the right order (remove Assembly_A.dll before Assembly_B.dll).

**What I tried to do**

<strike>I tried to influence the order of `@(AssembliesToDeploy)` by modifying project_B.targets like this:</strike>

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AssembliesToDeploy Include="Assembly_B.dll">
        <AssemblyType>SomeType</AssemblyType>
        <ApplicationName>App_B</ApplicationName>
    </AssembliesToDeploy>
    <AssembliesToDeploy Include="@(AssembliesToDeploy)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but when using project_B.targets inside project_B.proj the order inside `@(AssembliesToDeploy)` still remained Assembly_A.dll;Assembly_B.dll.

**Edit**

As MadGnome points out this cannot work because I'll end up with duplicates in `@(AssembliesToDeploy)`

**Is there a solution which would allow to reuse my .targets i.e not copying all ItemGroup elements to all .targets files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to include `project_B.targets` **before** `project_A`.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Start" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="project_B.targets" />
  <Import Project="project_A.targets" />    

  <Import Project="Common.targets" />
</Project>
```

---

I think there is a mistake in this code :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Generates duplicates if used with Import -->
  <AssembliesToDeploy Include="@(AssembliesToDeploy)" />

  <AssembliesToDeploy Include="Assembly_B.dll">
    <AssemblyType>SomeType</AssemblyType>
    <ApplicationName>App_B</ApplicationName>
  </AssembliesToDeploy>
</ItemGroup>
```

You are using `Import`, so you if you use the code above you'll have **duplicates** in `AssembliesToDeploy`.

Comment: If I chnage the order of the Import I'll have the same issue when processing `@(AssembliesToDeploy)`. You are absolutly right that my try will result in duplicates - resulting in Assembly_A.dll still being deployed before Assembly_B.dll. So your answer doesn't solve my issue but found the flaw in my approach.

Comment: Of course it's `@(AssembliesToRemove)` if I change the order of Import ... ctrl-c ctrl-v

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I added the final(?) solution as a new answer for completness sake.

Comment: What's the point of `<AssembliesToRemove Include="@(AssembliesToRemove)" />` ? Putting the same items that were already there?

Answer (score 0):

Adopting from **MadGnomes answer** I decided to split the ItemGroups into separate .target files.

**project_A_REMOVE.targets**

```
<Project xmlns="...">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssembliesToRemove Include="@(AssembliesToRemove)" />
        <AssembliesToRemove Include="Assembly_A.dll">
            <ApplicationName>App_A</ApplicationName>
        </AssembliesToRemove>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**project_A_DEPLOY.targets**

```
<Project xmlns="...">
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssembliesToDeploy Include="@(AssembliesToDeploy)" />
        <AssembliesToDeploy Include="Assembly_A.dll">
            <AssemblyType>SomeType</AssemblyType>
            <ApplicationName>App_A</ApplicationName>
        </AssembliesToDeploy>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the same for project_B.targets.

The **project_B.proj** now looks like this

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Start" xmlns="...">
    <Import Project="project_A_REMOVE.targets" />
    <Import Project="project_B_REMOVE.targets" />

    <Import Project="project_B_DEPLOY.targets" />
    <Import Project="project_A_DEPLOY.targets" />

    <Import Project="Common.targets" />
</Project>
```

Since my real solution consist of some 58 projects this will result in a lot of .targets. Even more so because I have to keep a common .targets for every project.